# formular with cyrillic in Xe/Lua

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, cyrillic

Cyrillic in formular (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/formular) does not work with (Xe/Lua)LaTeX, but works in pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{xparse}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{russian}
 \setotherlanguage{english}
 \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Extension=.otf]{cmunrm}
 \setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
 \setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\else
 \usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{formular}
\ifxetex\else
 \setFRMfontencoding{T2A}
 \setFRMdfontencoding{T2A}
\fi
\newFRMfield{namef}{15mm}[QwЙц]

\begin{document}
Тест: \useFRMfield{namef}[Джон]
\end{document}
```

Someone can help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

The `formular` package hardwires some font choices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{xparse}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{russian}
 \setotherlanguage{english}
 \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Extension=.otf]{cmunrm}
 \setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
 \setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\else
 \usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{formular}
\ifxetex
 \setFRMfontencoding{\encodingdefault}
 \setFRMdfontencoding{\encodingdefault}
 \setFRMfontfamily{\ttdefault}
 \setFRMdfontfamily{\sfdefault}
\else
 \setFRMfontencoding{T2A}
 \setFRMdfontencoding{T2A}
\fi
\newFRMfield{namef}{15mm}[QwЙц]

\begin{document}

Тест: \useFRMfield{namef}[Джон]

\end{document}
```

[image]